# Tomcat 7 manager /text interface does not work

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat-manager

I've just setup a new Tomcat 7.0.59 installation and added the Tomcat Manager application to web-apps. I'm able to login and use the web interface to manager via http://host:8080/manager/html as I could with Tomcat 6. The Tomcat 7 documentation (http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Manager_application) states:

> Note that the URL for the text interface has changed from "" to "/text"

The problem that I have is that using the */text* URI attribute doesn't work.

- http://host:8080/manager/list  (works)
- http://host:8080/manager/text/list (returns 404)

Is there some configuration setup that I need to do in order to get this to work properly?

Comment: I wonder what distribution you're using -- the tomcat manager should be included by default if you download tomcat from the official site: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

Comment: You'll also need to create a user entry in conf/tomcat-users.xml with 'manager-script' permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `tomcat-users.xml` to have a user with the `manager-script` role. It should look something like this:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user username="<username>" password="<password>" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

On my ubuntu system, the file is located in `/etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the recommendations for the manager-script role were important to solving my issue and for that I thank dnault and James for your feedback as I missed that in the documentation.

The biggest issue for the /manager/text not working was a bonehead mistake on my part. We breakout the catalina_home directory from the binary distribution of Tomcat. If I need manager for an installation, I create a symlink from the catalina_home/web-apps directory to the distribution web-apps/manager directory. In doing so, I linked it to the Tomcat 6 distro instead of Tomcat 7.

Changing the symlink and adding the manager-script solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause is server refuse maven's write action, Here my solution:

```
<user username="xxx" password="xxx" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
```